# How to edit the default navigator options of jqgrid using struts2-jquery tag?

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

I am using struts2-jquery grid plugin and would like to know if there's any option to modify navigator options like changing default add icon and title. This option is originally included in jqgrid API but I m afraid I cannot see it in the struts2-jquery plugin. Am I missing it or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not available in struts2-jquery grid plugin. We can either file a enhancement request or use a custom navigator button.